# How to show only a few pages using spry pagination

Tags: html, spry

I am using SPRY pagination, to paginate an XML dataset. Assume I have thousands of rows in the dataset, then SPRY pagination displays 100 pages. This forces my page to scroll horizontally, an effect I do not want. How can I achieve something like the one shown below or something equivalent:

```
<< < 1 2 3 4 5 .. 100 > >>
```

I have been trying this for days.
Please help me get a solution.

Thanks

```
var myOspatches = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("include/myxml.xml", "system/ospatches/patch");
var myOspatchesPage = new Spry.Data.PagedView( myOspatches ,{ pageSize: pSize , forceFullPages:true, useZeroBasedIndexes:true});
    var myOspatchesPageInfo = myOspatchesPage.getPagingInfo();
```

This is the pagination that dispays tonnes of pages

```
<table id="osPatchesPagination" style="width:100%;display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <!--<pre> <input type="button" class="btn" value="First" onclick="myOspatchesPage.firstPage();" /> <input type="button" class="btn" value="Prev" onclick="myOspatchesPage.previousPage();"/></pre>-->
            <pre> <a href="javascript:myOspatchesPage.firstPage();"><<</a> <a href="javascript:myOspatchesPage.previousPage();"><</a> </pre>

        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <span spry:region="myOspatchesPageInfo" spry:repeatchildren="myOspatchesPageInfo">
                <a spry:if="{ds_CurrentRowNumber} != {ds_RowNumber}" href="#" onclick="myOspatchesPage.goToPage('{ds_PageNumber}')">{ds_PageNumber}</a>
                <span spry:if="{ds_CurrentRowNumber} == {ds_RowNumber}" class="currentPage">{ds_PageNumber}</span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <pre> <a href="javascript:myOspatchesPage.nextPage();">></a> <a href="javascript:myOspatchesPage.lastPage();">>></a> </pre>
            <!--<pre> <input type="button" class="btn" value="Next" onclick="myOspatchesPage.nextPage();" /> <input type="button" class="btn" value="Last" onclick="myOspatchesPage.lastPage();" /></pre>-->
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i am typing up an answer now, so no need to repost your question

Comment: sorry, but while i fix my laptop (just crashed) as a temporary adjustment (not a fix) if the site is live and to keep the page numbers in a specific width, create a div container for them so the horizontal bar disappears

Answer (score 0):

Again this is not a full answer, but should give you a theoretical example.

After looking at the documentation, {ds_PageNumber} is what is needed to make this work. If you are only going to have say 10 page numbers, then doing some calculation into variables such as:

```
var currentPageMinus10 = {ds_PageNumber}-10;
```

should allow you to put build a nav bar yourself by linking this to an  tag.

Of couse if the current page - 10 is less than 1 or greater than the total number of pages, then  you will need to check and adjust accordingly.

[Documentation](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/articles/data_api/apis/pager.html#getpagecount)